# Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [xx] starting at [xx%]

Tags: angularjs, filter, syntax-error, special-characters

I have a sorting function. This function does not work if column name contains `%`.
For example `columnName == "calldrop"` my function works but `columnName == "calldrop%"` my function does not work and I get this error :

```
Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [RABPSHSDPAdrop%] starting at [RABPSHSDPAdrop%].
```

I dont know why.

```
$scope.applySorting = function (query, data) {
  var orderArray = query.sorting;
  // sortingArray == RABPSHSDPAdrop%
  var sortingArray = $.Enumerable.From(orderArray).Select(function (item) { return item.replace('data.', ''); }).ToArray();
  var sortedData = $.Enumerable.From($filter('orderBy')(data, sortingArray)).ToArray();  //broken here
  return sortedData;  
};
```

How can fix this case ? 
Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited this part and its work :

```
var sortingArray = $.Enumerable.From(orderArray).Select(function (item) { return item.replace('data.', '\'') + "'"; }).ToArray();
```

You have to use this : ''